# SQL: Selecting count of multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I don't think this will be too complicated to explain, but certainly complicated to get it working.

First of all, I have a couple of tables regarding users comments, one table for each section (forum, articles etc), as shown below:

site_users (id, username, ...) [Table that holds user's info]

site_articles_comments (id, user_id, comment, ...) [Where user_id = site_users.id]

site_forum_comments (id, user_id, comment, ...) [Same for site_articles_comments]

The thing is that every new row is a new comment and users can comment multiple times, which means that more rows are being added, thus making the need of sorting the number of rows to get the amount of comments in some sort of ranking system.

I was able to make a simple forum rank by doing this simple query:

> SELECT u.id, u.username, COUNT(r.id) AS rank FROM site_users AS u LEFT
>   JOIN site_forum_comments AS r ON u.id = r.user_id GROUP BY u.username,
>   u.id ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT :l

This query sorts all users from the database, where the user who has commented the most is always on top.

What I need, in the other hand, is to have a global ranking system, which sums the amount of comments in each section (articles, forum etc) and displays the users accordingly.

I was playing around with the sql to do that and the last thing I came up with was this huge query:

> SELECT u.id, u.username, (COUNT(a.id) + COUNT(f.id)) AS rank FROM
>   site_users u LEFT JOIN site_articles_comments a ON a.user_id = u.id
>   LEFT JOIN site_forum_comments f ON f.user_id = u.id GROUP BY 
>   u.username, u.id ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT :l

This, however, returns null. What could I possibly do to achieve the result I want?

Thanks in advance,

Mateus

EDIT1: Sorry for the lack of information, this is regarding MySQL.

Comment: Much things to be cleared still. Kindly explicitly explain what is that you want. Imean to say: **Sample of output** @MateusMelo

Comment: It would be even nicer if you could at least choose which DB platform we are discussing - you have both mysql and Oracle tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is math with nulls, and ordering with nulls (check into the "NULLS LAST" option for overriding the default ordering which returns the nulls first for a descending order).

In your case, with the outer joins, if the user has a ton of article comments but no forum comments, well, 100 + null = null in Oracle math. So to get the math to work you need to make null=0. That's where NVL() comes in (and also has the nice side-effect of eliminating pesky nulls from your result set)!

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, (NVL(COUNT(a.id),0) + NVL(COUNT(f.id),0)) AS rank 
FROM site_users u 
  LEFT JOIN site_articles_comments a ON a.user_id = u.id 
  LEFT JOIN site_forum_comments f ON f.user_id = u.id 
GROUP BY u.username, u.id ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT :l
```

I see you have both MySQL and Oracle in your tags - the above is for Oracle. If for MYSQL use COALESCE(COUNT(),0) instead.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying what was wrong and sorry for the lack of information.

Answer (score 0):

try `SELECT u.id, MIN(u.username) AS username, (COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT(a.id)),0) + COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT(f.id)),0)) AS rank 
FROM site_users AS u 
    LEFT JOIN site_articles_comments AS a ON (a.user_id = u.id)
    LEFT JOIN site_forum_comments AS f ON (f.user_id = u.id)
GROUP BY u.id 
ORDER BY rank DESC 
LIMIT :l`

Comment: Good Answer...!!! **Suggestion:** When you have a block of code. Try to leave a line above and below of that block and put 4 spaces on each lineof code. So it gets a more readable/presentable form.

Comment: One more thing, why is this query really slow when dealing with thousands of rows?