# Issues with JOIN constructions

Tags: mysql

Not long ago, I've asked a question here to find out the best way to rank users up by number of comments in each section of my website. If you wonder what the case was, click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899517/sql-selecting-count-of-multiple-tables).

The most suitable query for me was this one, which sums up all comments in every section, thus giving a global rank:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, (COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT(a.id)),0) + COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT(f.id)),0)) AS rank 
FROM site_users AS u 
LEFT JOIN site_articles_comments AS a ON (a.user_id = u.id)
LEFT JOIN site_forum_comments AS f ON (f.user_id = u.id)
GROUP BY u.id 
ORDER BY rank DESC 
LIMIT :l
```

While this suited me very well at the beggining of the website development, now, with more than 100k rows added to the database, it's almost impractical to handle such a large amount of data without compromising the entire website load time. Moreover, with this query in particular, site_articles_comments throws me an error regarding indexes:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 126 Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_3a0e6_0.MYI'; try to repair it'

Repairing the table didn't do anything, I believe indexes are not the problem, since I have them all set:

```
ALTER TABLE `site_articles_comments`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`);
```

What can I do to improve the query and to avoid this errors and overall website lag?

Thanks in advance,

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can cache result of the query, if displaying always most accurate rank is not crucial for you (and it sounds like that). You can then generate it once per 10minutes/1hr etc.

Comment: Have you overcome that problem?

Comment: I could get indexes to work properly, but still lacks performance. How can I get the query to be cached every 10 seconds?

Comment: I bet you don't need to refresh it every 10 seconds. The general idea is to calculate something once and then serve the same results to different users. So if you have one user visiting your page every minute, then you will not take any advantage of caching.

Caching could be done in your web app, in PHP code, not in DB. I've found for you some introduction about that topic: https://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/php-caching.php

That's just to give you some tips about the way which you can follow:)

Comment: Other option is database denormalization: storing the same information in different places, according to your requirements. Then you could have separate table user_rank, which you could or every time when someone is adding a comment, or from cron.

Comment: What about creating events so mysql can schedule a specific query to be executed every 24 hours? Something like CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `daily_update_ranking` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR STARTS '2016-03-24 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO ... (query)